# Common protected (Encrypted) partition for both Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, encryption

I have installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on my hard drive (Dual Boot). I like to have a common encrypted partition which will be available for both Windows and Ubuntu.

When I was using Windows as my only Operating System, I used BitLocker for this. Since now I'm using both Windows & Ubuntu, I cannot use BitLocker because BitLocker doesn't support Ubuntu.

So, What is the best way to have a common encrypted partition?
In addition, are there any partition formats/types (fat32, NTFS, etc.) specially designed for encryption?

Comment: what do you want, a encrypted partition so that it is available in both OS'es, if that is what you want that isn't going to work because it need windows developers and Linux developers to work together to create it, if you want your files to be hidden in windows, then format Ubuntu partition as anything except 'NTFS' and 'fat'. ext4 works well.

Comment: Cross site duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/1076784/common-protected-encrypted-partition-for-both-windows-and-ubuntu

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/376533/485660

Answer (score 1):

This might work with LUKS encrypted containers. You have to create one with

*cryptsetup -s 512 --hash sha256 luksFormat /dev/partitionNode*

(Soon to be released KDE Partition Manager 2.2 can also create luks partitions but at the moment you would have to compile it yourself)

Then open your encrypted device with

*cryptsetup open /dev/partitionNode cryptName*
and then format device /dev/mapper/cryptName with some filesystem.

Then there are a few options for inner FileSystem. Something like FAT32/NTFS will automatically work in both OSes. You can also try more advanced file systems like Btrfs with [btrfs driver for windows](https://github.com/maharmstone/btrfs)

You can try opening LUKS partitions in Windows using
[LibreCrypt](https://github.com/t-d-k/LibreCrypt).