# Shared encrypted partition for both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, encryption

Does there exists an out of the box or easy to use solution for having a shared encrypted partition for Windows and Ubuntu 20.04?

I found a related question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772178/common-protected-encrypted-partition-for-both-windows-and-ubuntu) for Ubuntu 16, but this one is not user friendly and needs separate software for accessing partition from Windows.